# Best practice for updates to a single datatable row

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

Why does the first method below work?  I would have thought that the variable 'row' is completely separate from anything else, such as a row in DataTable1.  Also, is there a drawback to using the first method?  For changes to lots of columns in a single row, I'd rather do it that way.

```
dim row = Me.DataSet1.DataTable1(0)
row.Item1=123
DataTable1TableAdapter.Update(Me.DataSet1.DataTable1)
```

OR

```
DataSet1.DataTable1(0).Item1=123
DataTable1TableAdapter.Update(Me.DataSet1.DataTable1)
```

Comment: both snippets are semantically identical. The only difference is that the first one has an intermediate variable. I'd day, use whichever seems more convenient/readable to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe setting row the way you are it is using vb .net type inference. when you set it equal to Me.DataSet1.DataTable1(0) any changes made to row will act as reference to Me.DataSet1.DataTable1(0).  @Bala you very right they are equivalent.

If i can interject personal preference i would definitely go with option two, no need to use a needless variable, and it's obviously cleaner and more straight forward to read.  AS far as a best practice, if you don't need the variable don't initialize it. especially one that directly references a value in your Table. Hope this helps.

Comment: So if I need to update a dozen columns in one row, isn't the 'behind-the-scenes' activity much greater if the second approach is used?

Comment: i don't believe so, in the first approach you a setting the value of row to Me.DataSet1.DataTable1(0). so on your next line, row.Item1=123, should be equivalent to DataSet1.DataTable1(0).Item1=123.  I'm fairly confident you would have the exact same processing speed independent of number of columns, you're just using an extra variable to pass a reference of the table first.  I don't think it would do any less work in the background just because it was called by reference. I could be missing something but from what i see in the code snippet, these are my conclusions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The variable 'row' is being set to the first row of table1.  Therefore, when you update table1, it pushes any changes made to 'row'.